# Trying to implement NFC in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, nfc, xamarin.forms

I found these instructions ([here](https://github.com/poz1/NFCForms)) on how to implement NFC with `Xamarin` forms / Android project.  I'm very new to this and the instructions are vague about reading a tag value.  Could someone please expand on how you would read a tag value and then use that value in your forms app.

Comment: It seems this is the answer to all questions today " [help] " since nobody has any clue what SO really is

Answer (score 0):

@ross, I use Alessandro Pozone plugin and for me it works well.
In github repository you find an "Example" directory. In "NFCFormSample" directory there is a NFCPage.cs file that "read" the NFC and display its values.
If you run this example, put a breakpoint in HandleNewTag method. In "e" parameter you should find all you need about your NFC

Have a nice day
Alessandro